# How to apply css style to popup title element of label

Tags: css, forms, element

I have a form label as follows:

```
<label id="jform_email-lbl" for="jform_email" class="hasTip required" 
title="Email Address::Please enter the email address associated with your User 
account.&lt;br /&gt;A verification code will be sent to you. Once you have 
received the verification code, you will be able to choose a new password for 
your account.">Email Address:<span class="star">&#160;*</span></label>
```

I want to apply a different style to my popover 'title' element (#000).

Not the 'Email Address:' label that shows on the form (which is #fff).

Thought I may be able to do the following, but it doesn't work:

```
label#jform_email-lbl[type="title"] { 
    color: #000; 
}
```

****EDITED**
The answer is as follows - for anyone else trying to find the right css:**

```
div.tip .tip-title {
   color: #E77600 !important;
   font-weight: bold;
}
div.tip .tip-text {
   color: #979797 !important;
   font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: title are already black, what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: in my css I have label{color: #fff;} - I want to leave that alone. but when you hover over the label, the text that pop's up/shows from the 'title' element is also white - i want that to be #000

Comment: @user991830 check my answer http://jsfiddle.net/zanTf/1/ i will update

Answer (score 3):

Later edit, i understood the question :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
label {
  color: #900;
  text-decoration: none;
}

label:hover {
  color: red;
  position: relative;
}

label[title]:hover:after {
  content: attr(title);
  padding: 4px 8px;
  color: red;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  z-index: 20px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #222;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #222;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #222;
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #cccccc);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,color-stop(0, #eeeeee),color-stop(1, #cccccc));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #cccccc);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #cccccc);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #cccccc);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #cccccc);
}


</style>
</head>

<label id="jform_email-lbl" for="jform_email" class="hasTip required" title="something">Email Address:<span class="star">&#160;*</span></label>

</html>
```

Comment: doesn't quite work - here is the url of the site/form label http://www.foxwellassociates.co.uk/account-login?view=reset hover over the label & you'll se what I mean

Comment: as how you can see here : http://jsfiddle.net/fQwbU/

if you dont put the hover command with relative the title wont show up red anymore :) you are missing that

Comment: Robert Voicu - i have dropped your css into Chrome Inspector on http://www.foxwellassociates.co.uk/account-login?view=reset - it changes the label color, but not the contents of the popup title text :(